# All videos move to left in Chrome when columns is used

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am using `-webkit-column-width` to create multiple columns of videos (videos on the youtube are used for testing purpose). It works well under IE. But it can not work under Chrome. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69zwwg2p/).

```css
.newspaper {
   -webkit-column-width: 300px;
      -moz-column-width: 300px;
           column-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="newspaper" align="center">
 
 <div style=" display: inline-block; border: 5px solid red;">
   <iframe style="border-radius: 5px; "  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mXaF92MmcV4"></iframe>
 </div>
    
 <div style=" display: inline-block; border: 5px solid red;">
   <iframe style="border-radius: 5px;"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7fdFGEg-9R8"></iframe>

 </div>
    
 <div style=" display: inline-block; border: 5px solid red;">
   <iframe style="border-radius: 5px; " src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/98xw8B3yOtM?list=RDTDDDvaoGiDg"></iframe>
 </div>
    
 <div style=" display: inline-block; border: 5px solid red;">
   <iframe style="border-radius: 5px;"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R67MAaKkH_U"></iframe>

 </div>
    
    </div>
```

When the width of the window is increased, there are multiple columns. The position of red box is right. But all the videos move to left and is in one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Chrome bug, I fixed it with this workaround: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/h621qy1j/)

```css
.newspaper {
    -webkit-column-width: 300px;
    -moz-column-width: 300px;
    column-width: 300px;
}

.video {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px solid red;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

.iframe {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="newspaper">
    <div class="video">
        <iframe class="iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mXaF92MmcV4"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
        <iframe class="iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7fdFGEg-9R8"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
        <iframe class="iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/98xw8B3yOtM?list=RDTDDDvaoGiDg"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
        <iframe class="iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R67MAaKkH_U"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Please, don't use inline styles.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that "-webkit-transform" is the solution. But I have no idea why.

Comment: @ChengchengPei I think it's render issue in Chrome, read about using `translateZ(0)` — https://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/.